# Reduce a list by filtering out repeated elements

Tags: python

I want to reduce a list to its sequence. Or I could say I want to remove duplicate neighbors in a list.

This Python code does what I want.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
data = [True, False, False, False, False, True, True]
expected = [True, False, True]

result = []
for d in data:
    try:
        if result[-1] != d:
            result.append(d)
    except IndexError:
        # Happens in first iteration
        result.append(d)

print(result)
```

Here is a second approach with less lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
data = [True, False, False, False, False, True, True]
expected = [True, False, True]

result = [data[0]]
for d in data[1:]:
    if result[-1] != d:
        result.append(d)

print(result)
```

But I assume there is a better and more pythonic way.

**EDIT**: Of course this code should go into a function. But this is not the core of the question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two programs are pretty similar, just that the first skips `data[0]` by catching an exception, whilst the second does it by slicing it off the input.

In both cases, we have inlined the logic directly into the program; I think it would be better to create a function and give it a good name - perhaps `uniq`, based on the standard command that does a similar thing with lines of input.  Writing a function also gives us somewhere to document its behaviour and (using `doctest`) to provide some simple unit tests.

When I want to transform a sequence, I turn first to [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).  In this case, I find it has a convenient [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function that's pretty much what we want (it even mentions that it's similar to `uniq`).  So all we have to do is to take the key element from each tuple returned by `itertools.groupby(data)`:

```
import itertools

def uniq(sequence):
    '''
    Replace any repeated elements in "sequence" with a single element.
    Examples:
    >>> uniq([])
    []
    >>> uniq([True, False, False, False, False, True, True])
    [True, False, True]
    '''
    return [k for k,g in itertools.groupby(sequence)]
```

This can be tested in the usual way:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: I do know `itertools` but don't understand most of it. It is hard for me to transform the description in the docs into real world problems.

Comment: Consider doing some "kata" exercises that improve your familiarity with iterators, including generators and `itertools`.  Those are very useful concepts in Python, and practice is the best way to improve your understanding and confidence with them.  Perhaps also search this site for uses of `itertools` that you can follow and re-create from the problem description?

Answer (score 4):

**Put your code in functions**. Among other benefits, it's easier to test
that way.

**Consider using `itertools.groupby`**. If given no key function, it
organizes the data based on adjacent runs of equal values.

```
from itertools import groupby

def neighboring_dups_removed(data):
    return [k for k, group in groupby(data)]
```

Comment: I ended up making the same points in my answer (which I wrote without seeing this, but got interrupted by a meeting before I could submit it).  It's good to see we were thinking along exactly the same lines.